# Showing that $\sum k^{2}/k!=e^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble seeing why $\sum_{k=1} k^{2}/k!=e^2$. The ratio test says that it converges absolutely. Pardon my ignorance, but are there any techniques to show this?

I thought about expanding $e^{2}= e \cdot e =(\sum_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!})(\sum_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!})$ but so far that hasn't helped me much.

Comment: See the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ (it is google-able)

Comment: @SimpleArt Given the question, it looks like the OP is aware of that.

Comment: Sorry guys for the mistake and the duplicate, I voted to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have misread your source, this is *not* equal to $e^2$, but to $2e$. Unrolling the expression,
$$\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^2}{k!} 
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{k!} 
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{(k-1)!} 
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+1}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{k!} +\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \\
&
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{k!} +e^1 
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k-1)!} +e^1 
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} +e^1 
= e^1  +e^1 \\
&= 2e
\end{align}$$

Comment: All too easy.  +1.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{k^2}{k!}&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{k}{(k-1)!}
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{k-1}{(k-1)!}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{(k-1)!}
\\ &=
\sum_{k=2}^\infty  \frac{k-1}{(k-1)!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{k!}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty  \frac{1}{(k-2)!}+e 
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{k!}+e =2e
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$ e^x= \sum \frac{x^k}{k!} $

$ e^x= (e^x)'= \sum \frac{x^{(k-1)}}{(k-1)!} $

$ x e^x = \sum \frac{x^k}{(k-1)!} $

$ (x e^x)' = (x+1)e^x = \sum \frac{k x^{(k-1)}}{(k-1)!} = \sum \frac{k^2  x^{(k-1)}}{k!} $

so $2e = \sum \frac{k^2}{k!}$

Answer (score 0):

No. Actually,

$\sum_{k=0} 2^{k}/k!=e^2$

Comment: The fact that another series has sum $e^2$ does not mean that this one cannot sum to $e^2$. (In this case, it does not, but the argument is not a valid one.)

Comment: @ClementC.  sure. But many people throw random slop here without proofreading. I might have worried, but you and another found the actual value of the series as typed.